# Handle 500 internal error in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-errors

I am new to Django rest. Now what my understanding is that in case of a 500 internal error, django will send a html page with message server error 500, if debug=False in settings.py. But what i want is to send a custom json object with error code , status etc in that exception message instead of that html page. Please suggest me how to proceed with that custom exception handling.

Comment: Could you share your codes and error messages?

Comment: @kamilyrb that is where i am stuck..not able to figure out how to proceed. My scenario is  what i have stated above. I  want to know the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom view and set the path to the view as [`handler500`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.handler500) in your project's root `urls.py` file.